# 250k connections for comet with node.js

Tags: nginx, haproxy, node.js, high-load

How to implement node.js to be able to handle 250k connections as comet server (client side we use socket.io)?

Would the use of nginx as proxy/loadbalancer be the right solution? Or will HA-Proxy be the better way? Has anyone real world experience with 100k+ connections and can share his setup?
Would a setup like this be the right one (Quad core CPU per server -> start 4 Instances of node.js per Server?):

```
  nginx (as proxy / load balancing server)
        /               |          \
       /                |           \
      /                 |            \
     /                  |             \
node server #1  node server #2  node server #3
4 instances     4 instances     4 instances
```

Comment: YouPorn runs with nginx as load balancer so I'm pretty confident it can handle your load :P

Comment: @AntoineBenkemoun "Handle your load" may have been an unfortunate choice of words there.

Comment: @AntoineBenkemoun Our requirement of 250K tcp connections is another playarea and far away from a few hundred http req/sec that a site like YP makes.

Answer (score 1):

vanilla nginx doesn't support HTTP/1.1 keepalive to the upstream (backend) servers, which breaks socket.io :(  If you're willing to compile it yourself, you may have better luck --> http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets

Though at that scale I wonder if it would be smoother to skip the web server layer, routing the TCP connections directly...

Comment: Thank you for the Link. I need to check if HA-Proxy is able to make a proper TCP routing. Would like to hear if anyone has some Real World experience.

Comment: since 1.1.4 nginx has `ngx_http_upstream_keepalive` module and `proxy_http_version` directive

Comment: @SaveTheRbtz great news, I hope they release soon a stable version that include the proxy_http_version directive.